# Extending django form with fields not in model, results in error that only lists can be concatenated, not tuples

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am completing an eCommerce application, and the final stage is implementing the order form and processing payments with stripe.

I want to show one form to the user where they can input their customer details, as well as card details (card number, expiry dates and cvv) that will be sent to stripe, but will not be stored locally. Hence, there are no fields relevant to storing card numbers in the model I am using for my form.

In looking for an answer to my query, I came [across](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229039/django-modelform-with-extra-fields-that-are-not-in-the-model) this question and answer, which seems to be the solution.

However, when I attempt to extend my form in the same way, I get an error:

```
fields = OrderForm.Meta.fields + ('card_num', 'exp_month', 'exp_year', 'cvc')
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list
```

From what I can see, I am doing the exact same thing as proposed in the answer to that question, so I am unsure why I am getting this error.

My forms.py that I am extending:

```
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email',
        'address', 'zipcode', 'city', 'state']
```

And my attempt to extend the form in my views.py:

```
class OrderPayForm(OrderForm):

    card_num = forms.CharField(max_length=16)
    exp_month = forms.CharField(max_length=2)
    exp_year = forms.CharField(max_length=4)
    cvc = forms.CharField(max_length=3)

    class Meta(OrderForm.Meta):
        fields = OrderForm.Meta.fields + ('card_num', 'exp_month', 'exp_year', 'cvc')
```

Is there something I am missing where I am doing something different from what is in the accepted answer that I am following?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you exactly what's wrong. Use a list instead of a tuple:

```
fields = OrderForm.Meta.fields + ['card_num', 'exp_month', 'exp_year', 'cvc']
```

Comment: Oh my goodness....so obvious in hindsight. I was looking over things quite a few times before deciding to post and I couldn't see it. Well, thank you!

Comment: I would actually prefer to delete this question since I don't think it adds value to the site, but you would have to remove your answer for me to do so. Do let me know if you agree, otherwise, thank you for answering.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the site policy on this sort of thing. Can you point me toward some documentation clarifying when a question should or should not be deleted?

Comment: It's up to you if you want to or not, there is no set policy on this type of thing AFAIK.